# pysolr search result different from apache solr cloud result with the same query

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

I have a query in pysolr and which is weird that the result is different from what I query in solr cloud.

In pysolr

```
query="filename:(articles\\56.txt OR articles\\400.txt OR articles\\304.txt) ^20 AND filtered:(empire OR collapse OR Alexander OR 's OR conquests)^20 AND label:(TIME OR DATE)^20 OR lemmatized:(empire,collapse,Alexander,'s,conquest)^10 OR root: (collapse) ^10
solr.search(q=query, **{'q.op':'AND'}, start=0, rows=10)"
```

This can't give any result in pysolr

But when I input the query in solr cloud, it actually gives me the result.

[Solr Cloud result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8RLq.jpg)

This is really frustrating, can anyone help me with this?
Or pysolr's q.op is not work the same as solr cloud's q.op?
Is that possible?

Comment: It turns out that I can't use filename:(1.txt, 2.txt). The ',' can't be OR in pysolr, I have to use filename(1.txt OR 2.txt). Then q.op will work.